# When a transaction is broadcast to the network, what is actually being sent?

Tags: transactions, hash

When a transaction is broadcasted to the network, what is being sent? Is it a hash? if yes, is it going to be the hash of: previous transaction + public key of the receiver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Client creates a new transaction, adds it to its memory pool
- Client broadcasts an `inv` frame, which indicates that it has something in its memory pool, by giving the hash of the transaction to one or more connected peers
- Peer receives `inv` frame, checks its own memory pool, it's not in there, so it sends a `getdata` frame back
- Client receives a `getdata` frame for the transaction it just created, so it sends a `tx` with the entire transaction
- Peer receives the `tx`, hashes it and puts it in the memory pool
- Peer now has something new in the memory pool, and broadcasts an `inv` to all connected peers
- Client gets an `inv` frame, notices that it's already in the memory pool, and ignores it
- Another client gets the `inv` frame as well, `getdata`'s it, stores the `tx`, sends `inv`, and repeat that until the entire network has the transaction.

References :

- [tx frame](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx)
- [inventory vector](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Inventory_Vectors)
- [getdata](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#getdata)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't bitcoin only send the transaction to one peer if it originated the transaction?

Comment: @NickODell Perhaps, but that's implementation related, and not a network rule.

Comment: Thank you Tom, very clear explanation. However, I still have a question. Based on Satoshi paper http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf, the hash consists of the public key of the receiver too. I suppose that the public key is added in order to have different hashes?

Comment: (Disclaimer: I've never read the paper, I've only built a client.) The hash of a transaction is simply the entire transaction (`tx`) hashed (unlike blocks, which only have their headers hashed). This includes all the inputs and outputs.

Comment: how fast or how long does it take to broadcast the information to all peers? i mean when i'm mining, and somebody has already found a new block, how long would it take till i receive the information and start mining again on new block?

Comment: Reaching *all* peers can take a long time (maybe even up to an hour), as there are always a few edges on the network where it takes a lot longer. However, for most nodes it's a matter of seconds to maybe two minutes.