# Transaction broadcasted to the Bitcoin network but not in my mempool

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, armory, mempool

I use armoryd (0.93.1) to send transactions in the testnet Bitcoin network with the three calls:
1. createustxtoaddress
2. signasciitransaction
3. sendasciitransaction

The calls are all successfull, the transaction is broadcasted then mined. 
BUT it's never appeared in the mempool !
according to this dicussion : [When a transaction is broadcast to the network, what is actually being sent?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9864/when-a-transaction-is-broadcast-to-the-network-what-is-actually-being-sent) how is this possible ?!

test realized at 1:42 PM Today

> my txId: 814555d2fa93f1f01f84cfadff753cb66594d5fd1205523f82c44ac4da6f5359
>
> bitcoin core mempool: [
>       "135ec8b33e79b1a827b474b31460afc6f94104a9d33fea86bf77b38ffcc89bab",
>       "3319496f02e377451bc0b27951e488a60a3a4f9dc2c6c5ae3a350e42a0a32d2d",
>       "3a1e3674de34013aa45b96d680bd39a29c6ca5b4bcdccdef12dbb03d5a76b72e",
>       "4737ec977a4bd256fc9f6250221ea8b935a8c2f0769b62a2e43f9ad685980bef",
>       "4d8c4d8f67536007c826de9d2b65a8e566736cba8d80d3c77fe696909624602e",
>       "4ec4d33aa4ec6ff136715c5301cc0571220210a417c69479c0bd1a41a6b2a8bb",
>       "54a2b0d2e010b1c94f59f5970c882167ad4746c778f23334da4cb9bb9850a203",
>       "54e6b52cbbd93efcd33d6f5f38daa538e467401dbd6b1e6ce93f8f9089caf071",
>       "75c0765c97805ff6bc7e383d5b927620cf39afa87f061784e94aa092c10c9b57",
>       "9c47af29649f2ca07f6203e3b88ab9d723b93cd19c98b9bf8e218306bdfdec15",
>       "a982220cc1c6ecd437e1a0f7cd7f99df19b7841c4f1ca4117f57c2e6fd90c153",
>       "b3b1a483d9c8151a1bf48b81d4a4aa9193a640078d2e0af0d2b8b8eb673790dc",
>       "b6392de0a579a413c224cd379b8d0e6ecd66283fdfd88e1356c8a299200db90a",
>       "bd4d9ade8b362548007c0780be1e35a065af9e29ee0ae2f43950b8b192d9865b",
>       "c1f02ab8686fc2f678e77ecf4d79cc5f827dd709efd9d3262a66f14b34b8a376",
>       "c66958ca3f9a2c526e72a84ac061a5bd31485aa757000badf2049ab386d61054",
>       "d2bd27f1c4e42d92781448adada8c7c7c8df701ea23ca66c259c3f4ec90e3f8a",
>       "e7c3b7e81cea9cd1d361725c0d0c6bb30f9f63fe882d5d7bd65b12207e13e4ce",
>       "ef1838102e2200d73003a147de124bce19efcd98c7334c6f67c97b63f89ff26d"
>   ]

This is not a synchro problem no block are mined in the meanwhile. If anyone has a clue..

Comment: I haven't used this client. May be a feature in it that it broadcasts raw transaction to a network but does not keep it into mempool because of some reasons, for example low fees? You have to do more tests with sending raw transactions.

Comment: Even if armory don't put directly the transaction in the mempool I should receive it from the other nodes, so where is this transaction ?

I'll be more specific, I use armory for a long time now (3 months and more than 500 transactions) and check automatically the bitcoin mempool for the transactions I send because sometimes armory mess up with the transaction broadcast. This behaviour is new and I can reproduct it.

Comment: Your peers should not send transaction back to you, even notify you about it because they assume that you have it already :)

Comment: Ok.. any clue of how I can get this transaction back in my mempool ?

Comment: Confirmed in block transaction should not exist in mempool. You have to do more tests. I can not answer your question, just speculating

Comment: I know I want it back before the first block ;) 
I'll investigate more, if anything comes out I'll notify it here.